# Restoring multiple window excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was looking at an Excel sheet in two windows - xxx.xls:1 and xxx.xls:2 when we had a powercut.  Now, when I open up the sheet, I can see xxx.xls:2 but not xxx.xls:1.  If I try to open up another window, it becomes xxx.xls:3.  I've tried tiling, rearranging etc - only have one window called xxx.xls:2.

It occasionally asks questions when I'm running vba.  I don't know whether these are normal or whether they are caused by the lack of :1.  Questions like the sheet is already open: do you wish to close it.

Question: how do I restore xxx.xls:1.  I've looked through all the menu/ribbon options; I can't see anything obvious.

Comment: That seems to be some wrong setting stuck after the power cut, try to restart your pc.

Comment: Do you mean you want to recover a lost book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have two windows of the same workbook, but one of them is hidden or minimized. Please try the following from your `:2` window.

**First, let's check if the window is hidden:**

1. Under the `View` tab, click the `Unhide` button. If the button is disabled it means the window isn't hidden and you can skip step 2.
2. Select the hidden window from the dialog and click `OK`. You should now see it.

**If that did not solve the problem, maybe the window is minimized somewhere:**

1. Under the `View` tab click `Arrange All`.
2. In the dialog that opens (see screenshot below) select the `Tiled` or `Vertical` option and check the `Windows of active workbook` checkbox.
3. Click `OK`.

If the `:1` window is open somewhere you should be able to see it now. You can close it or maximize it etc.

[image]

Note: You did not specify which version of Excel you're using. The screenshot is from Excel 2010 but the procedure above should be similar in other versions.

Comment: The sheet was hidden.  Also, I didn't have the excel window wide enough so I didn't even see that the unhide button was enabled.